# Is it random to split ordered data on every ith entry?

Tags: machine-learning, randomness

I have an ordered set of data, X, that I want to split into a 10 random groups to do 10-fold cross validation. The data set is very simple with one feature per row. I am wondering if it is random/accepted practice in Machine Learning to split the data into the ten groups by iterating over the data placing the data into the groups every ten entries. So, for example, I start at X[0] and that would go into a group called "group0", X[1] would go into "group1". Once I reach X[10], I would place that in "group0" again. I would repeat this until all data is in one of the ten groups. First of all is this random? Secondly, if it isn't random, does it matter? Will the averaging of the ten folds counteract any "non-randomness" with a sufficiently large data-set?

Comment: This is called *systematic sampling.*  It is used where necessary, but with caution: circumstances can occur where this approach produces extraordinarily unrepresentative subsamples--and sometimes they crop up unexpectedly.  As an example, what if your data were daily measurements of business activity and you decided to do 7-fold cross validation?  Some of your groups would consist of all Sundays or all Saturdays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into the philosophy of what randomness means, no, this is pretty deterministic. But does it matter?

Let us recap why you do such things. You typically do it because you want the left out fold to be an unbiased estimate of your generalisation error. So if your aim is to optimise some loss function $\ell(x)$ on you data set $\mathcal{D} = \{x_i\}$, you typically do that because you want to minimize the empirical risk:

$$\mathbb{E}[\ell(x)]_{x \sim p(x)},$$

where $p(x)$ is the *empirical distribution*, representing the source of your data. E.g. if you have a data set consisting of 1000 cat pictures, you can interpret this to be a sample from the distribution that generates cat pictures.

We typically approximate the risk by a finite sample

$$\mathbb{E}[\ell(x)]_{x \sim p(x)} \approx \frac{1}{|F|} \sum_{i \in F} \ell(x_i),$$
where $F$ is the set of samples in the current fold.

Back to your question. Is taking every i'th sample from your data giving you a reliable sample of the generalisation error? That is the case if it is an unbiased sample of your empirical distribution. Whether this is the case is of course tough to answer without knowing where the data comes from. But even if you know where the data comes from, you might just be wrong.

To be on the save side, creating $F$ by sampling with replacement from $\mathcal{D}$ is preferred. Additional care has to be taken that the samples you use to select your model (i.e. $\mathcal{D} \setminus F$) have to be independent of the samples you use to evaluate it (i.e. $F$). This can be challenging in some context, e.g. time series. When you train a model to predict stocks, you don't want to just sample randomly with replacement because samples from the same day will be highly correlated.